# Embed wav in java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource, javasound

I was writing a little alarm clock program that plays an audio file several times when the alarm time is up.

The alarm side of the program is done. Now I'm down to playing the file. I use the jFileChooser to select the file. The javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream , javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem and javax.sound.sampled.Clip to play my wav file. Working as well.

But I really just want to play one wav file and I also want to be able to move this alarm clock on multiple systems so I want to avoid using jFileChooser to chose my alarm tone. I don't want to have to browse and chose the file every time i run the program.

Would it be easier to give the file a relative path (in the same folder as the jar, for example) and then fix the path string?
Or would it be easier to somehow make the wav a part of the jar file (which is what i would prefer as then i woudn't have to worry about the wav file at all. It would be just one jar file independently functioning as an alarm clock. A byte array,maybe?)

Thanks in advance!
Sorry if this is too dumb. I'm a newbie!

Here's my code for the AudioInputStream.

```
 public void getaudPath() {
try {
    JFileChooser chooser;
   String choosertitle=null;
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "WAV only", "wav");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        apath = (chooser.getSelectedFile()).toString();
      File soundFile = new File(apath);
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
     URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(apath);
         clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(audioIn);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Got file, A-okay!");
}  else {
          apath = null;
      }} catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error in getting sound file:=> "+e); }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

- Add the audio clip to a Jar
- Add the Jar to the run-time class-path of the app.  (not necessary if the clip and classes are in the same Jar).
- Use `Class.getResource("/path/to/the.wav)` to get an URL to the clip.
- Play the clip using code based on that seen in the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

> File objects are required for AudioInputStream.

**No they are not!**  Here is a copy/paste of the source to which I referred you on the Java Sound info. page.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It uses an **URL** for getting the `AudioInputStream`, not a `File`.

The call to `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` is overloaded to accept 5 different argument types.  The most important/generic 3 are.

- [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.File%29)
- [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) **&**
- [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.net.URL%29)

Comment: File soundFile = new File(apath);

AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

     URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(apath);

         clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

         clip.open(audioIn);

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Got file, A-okay!");

Like so?

Comment: 1) Please don't put code in comments.  Edit it into the question, use code formatting, and notify me in a comment that the question has been edited.  2) A `File` is of absolutely no use for anything to do with `getResource(String)`.  In case you are confused, it takes a path relative to the class-path (leading `/`) or the package of the class (no leading `/`).

Comment: 1)Sincerest apologies!
2)Yes, but File objects are required for AudioInputStream.

Comment: 1)Fixed.
2) It throws a NullPointerException. I've put up my code.

Comment: *"It throws a NullPointerException"*  That does not surprise me.  Why does it surprise you?  Again, **"A `File` is of absolutely no use for anything to do with `getResource(String)`."**  You might extend that to include `JFileChooser`.  The relative path would be a hard-coded string, using `getResource(String)`.  We know where the clip will be stored (we put it there) so that works well.